# Font for good looking `--` and `@` in an lstlinsting

Tags: fonts, symbols, listings

I am using `\lstset` in order to create boxes with writing in in my document. In these boxes I am using a lot of double dash (`--`) and a lot of at symbol (`@`). I am trying to change `basicstyle` to ensure that both symbols (`--`, `@`) come out nicely. I could not find a list of `basicstyle`s and for everything I tried either the `@` looks weird and is hard to read or the space between each dash in `--` is so small that it looks like a single long dash.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[DIV=14,BCOR=2mm,headinclude=true,footinclude=false]{typearea}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\lstset{backgroundcolor = \color{backcolour}, breaklines=true, language=bash,basicstyle=\rmfamily}


\begin{document}
\chapter*{Test}


% Okay-ish at symbol but the double dash is ugly
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
--PN 4 @ 
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{backgroundcolor = \color{backcolour}, breaklines=true, language=bash,basicstyle=\sffamily}

% Both the double dash and the at symbol look ugly
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
--PN 4 @ 
\end{lstlisting}


\lstset{backgroundcolor = \color{backcolour}, breaklines=true, language=bash,basicstyle=\ttfamily}

% Good looking double dash but the at symbol is ugly
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
--PN 4 @ 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Here is a list of monospaced fonts: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very opinion based, since there is now way of telling, what you consider good looking.

Instead of answering the unanswerable question, I will rather show you where to find fonts, and how to use them.

You should use monospaced fonts for code. You can find some in the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html). Usually you can just copy the code from the example page and you are good to go:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{DejaVuSansMono}
%% Another possibility is
%% \usepackage{dejavu}
%% which loads the DejaVu Serif and DejaVu Sans fonts as well
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be typewriter style
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\lstset{backgroundcolor = \color{backcolour}, breaklines=true, language=bash,}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
--PN 4 @ 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

How does it look?

[image]

You are using DejaVuSansMono for your listings now:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
UFFTXN+DejaVuSansMono                Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
```